# Carcassonne city scoring

Tags: carcassonne

If a city has two knights for one player and one knight for another, does the player with two knights get the double point bonus for that city?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by double point bonus? I have never heard of this term before.

Comment: By castle do you mean city? And... are you saying that the thing you were asking about doesn't actually exist, so there's no question to answer here anymore?

Comment: Yes - please delete!

Answer (score 4):

When the city is completed, the player(s)<sup>[1]</sup> with the most knights in the city gets points for the city in the amount of two per tile plus two per banner<sup>[2]</sup>. No other player receives any points for that city.

For example, when completing a three-tile city without banners, the player with two knights will receive 6 points, and the player with one knight will receive none, just like if there was only one knight in the city.

---

1. In the event of a tie, each of the players tied for the most knights gets all of the points.
2. Half that for incomplete cities at the end of the game.

---

> A city is complete when it is surrounded by walls and there are no gaps in the walls or the city. There can be any number of sections in a city. **A player who owns a knight in a completed city scores 2 points per tile in the city (count the tiles and not the sections). Each banner in the scored city also gives the player 2 points.**
>
> **What if there are more than one follower on a completed road or city?** With some clever tile placements, it is possible to connect road and city sections, resulting in a road with more than one thief or a city with more than one knight. **The player with the most thieves or knights scores the totality of the points. In case of a tie, the tied players each score the points.**
>
> During the final scoring, **incomplete** roads, cities or monasteries are scored. A player who has a follower on an incomplete road, city or monastery scores **1 point per tile**. For cities, **each banner is also worth only 1 point**. In case of a tie, use the same rules as for **completed** features.

(Emphasis in original)

Comment: My wife and I fought for hours about this rule. I pointed out this in the rule book. She admitted that my interpretation was exactly what was in the rule book, but that her interpretation was how we'd be playing. *shrug*

Answer (score -1):

If by double point you mean banner or other point influence in an expansion, yes. The winner of the meeple showdown wins it all, no divisions except in case of ties.

Comment: There's no division of points even when there is a tie. "In case of a tie, the tied players each score the points." More importantly, banner points **aren't** doubled for having two knights. (I don't know anything about influence.)